# Concat multiple JSON into one CSV in Pandas, dict error

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I've multiple json that I want to convert into a single csv with pandas. Here's my code:

```
import json
import os
import pandas as pd

data = []

for file in os.listdir("json"):
    if file.endswith(".json"):
        print(file)
        data = json.load(open(os.path.join("json", file)))
        df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'items')
        print(df)
        data.append(df)
temp = pd.concat(data, ignore_index = True) #concat different dataframe
temp.to_csv("output.csv", index=False, sep='\t', encoding="utf-8") #write to csv file
```

But I get this error: `data.append(df)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'`

What am I doing wrong? In all the documentation and examples I've studied it seems the right thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning `data` as a list:

```
data = []
```

...but then re-assigning it here (which is a dict):

```
data = json.load(open(os.path.join("json", file)))
```

Use a different variable name.